# Unity3D Android Java Plugin : Button added on UnityPlayer Activity -> touch not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, unity-game-engine

I'm making a binding from Unity3D to a Java SDK. That Java SDK adds a View (RelativeLayout) to the current Activity (UnityPlayer.currentActivity) with an android.widget.Button in it.

The view is perfectly displayed but when the user touches/tap the button, the OnClickListener.onClick method of the button isn't called.

The view with the button is added using this code :

```
UnityPlayer.currentActivity.addContentView(view, params);
```

I think that Unity probably catches all user touch events. Is it possible to forward them so that the Button can fire the onClick ? Is there another way ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit : 
I tried to add in my Manifest for com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity :

`<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />`

But no result so far :(

Comment: No, unfortunatly no. Instead of adding a view to the unityPlayer.currentActivity, I finally created a new activity with a translucent background to do what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a workaround while trying to solve this in one of my projects.

Solution:

1. ProxyActivity is the first activity that comes up. This opens Activity or NativeActivity, depending on the android version.
2. Make sure that the Activiy (not the NativeActivity) is shown. Code snippet to change in ProxyActivity:

> Class activity = Class.forName(classNames[0]);

^^ Always force it to open the class which extends Activity and not the Native one.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, Unity is catching the input.
If you want to capture the input instead of Unity - you have to put your view into a separate window (Dialog), or create your own Activity. Both options are creating their own input loops hence overriding Unity loop.